# How do you set a gradient background colour for the Form in Visual C++?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linear-gradients

I'm new to working with Visual Studio 2010. 
I want to know how to set the background colour of a form to be a gradient colour in c++. 
I saw some source online but that was for Visual Basic .NET.

appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to get used to finding .NET sample code in vb.net or C# syntax, writing Winforms code in C++/CLI is not often done.  The translation is rather mechanical so be sure to get a decent on book on C++/CLI programming so you can just rattle it off yourself.

Anyhoo, the code is pretty simple, just override the OnPaintBackground method and modify the constructor so the form will redraw itself whenever the size is changed:

```
protected:
    virtual void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs^ e) override {
        System::Drawing::Drawing2D::LinearGradientBrush brush(Point::Empty, Point(this->ClientSize.Width, this->ClientSize.Height), Color::Yellow, Color::Blue);
        e->Graphics->FillRectangle(%brush, 0, 0, this->ClientSize.Width, this->ClientSize.Height);
    }
```

Constructor:

```
Form1(void) {
    InitializeComponent();
    SetStyle(ControlStyles::ResizeRedraw, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You're right, it does look very similar to the C# code I read earlier.